# HTML generated by angular js controller not handled by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs with jquery 1.9.1 and bootstrap 3.x for developing single page web application.
I am generating my html file from my controller like:

```
    var fieldData='<div class="box1 input-group date">';
    fieldData=fieldData+'<label for="dob" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">Date Of Birth (mm/dd/yy)</label>';
    fieldData=fieldData+'<div class="input-group date col-md-8">';
    fieldData=fieldData+'<input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphiconglyphicon-th"></i></span>';
    fieldData=fieldData+'</div></div>';

document.getElementById("calcDiv").innerHTML =fieldData;
```

my index.html contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="calcApp">

    <head>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <!-- lib/angularjs  -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/angular/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/simple-slider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="css/simple-slider-volume.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
    </head>

<body >

<div ng-include='"view/header.html"'></div>

    <div class="container" ng-controller="calcController">

<div class="des-ail clearfix" id="calcDiv"> 

</div>

    </div>

<!--------------- javascript ---------->
<script src="lib/common/jquery-1.9.1.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/common/bootstrap.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript"  src="js/apps/application.js"></script>
<script  type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/calcController.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/common/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/common/respond.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib/common/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Output is generated successfully but date picker is not working.

similarly other html controls that are generated by angular js controller are not being manipulated by jquery like jquery-sliders and other jquery-methods.

Note:
if I am simply writing that html code in index.html like

```
<div class="box1 input-group date">
                <label for="dob" class="col-md-4 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">Date Of Birth (mm/dd/yy)</label>
                <div class="input-group date col-md-8">

                    <input type="text" class="form-control"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th"></i></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**then it is being manipulated by jquery.**

Comment: you have a missing `>` character at the label. `</label` <!-- here comes a `>` at the second row.

Comment: where is the datepicker?

Comment: Why are you not just using a template HTML file along with your controller? The way you are doing it is considered a bad practice. o

Comment: @lolka_bolka my html is rendering correctly by angular js but that html is not being manipulated by jquery while hard-coded html is being manipulated correctly by jquery.

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating dynamic html, then the $(".datepicker").datepicker(); should be called on insert of each element and not on load.

Comment: please give me example or fiddle for the same.FYI,  the date picker code is this :                             $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
    startDate: "2012-01-01",
    endDate: "2015-01-01",
    todayBtn: "linked",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
    });

Comment: The html is hard coded in given example and there is no angularjs i was talking about html generated through angularjs controller not handled by jquery